# Setting console resolution in Ubuntu Server 13.10 within VMware

Tags: server, grub2, 13.10, vmware, display-resolution

I've completed an install of Ubuntu Server 13.10 within VMware and am running into a problem configuring the console (non-graphical) resolution.

When I was running Ubuntu Server 13.04, I ran into the same problem. [posted the question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299975/proper-way-to-change-terminal-resolution-in-ubuntu-server-13-04), which I later solved by editing `/etc/default/grub` thus:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash vga=789"
```

I then ran `sudo update-grub`, `sudo reboot` and 13.04 stuck in a larger-size console mode... just what I wanted. BUT when I run the same commands in 13.10, during the reboot it changes to the new screen-res, BUT the screen stays black and I can't interact with it. I power down the VM, go back to a previous snapshot, and try again... and again.

Since the `hwinfo` package is no longer available, I can't run `sudo hwinfo --framebuffer` to see what options are available.

Ideas anyone?

Here are the uncommented settings in my `/etc/default/grub` file at this moment:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="find_preseed=/preseed.cfg"
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY=false
GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600
```

Answer (score 1):

#### An alternative option, in short -

1. A. Either use bridged network to guest

   B. Or, follow directions at [1] to forward port 22 (ssh port) to a host port
2. SSH to the host port (and thereby to the guest), using Putty or any other ssh client. The ssh client should give you a re-sizable console.

#### TL;DR

I recently upgraded my VM and ran into the same problem. I tried various combinations of values for GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, GRUB_GFXMODE, GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD, and GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX to no avail. I have gone for an alternative that now works better for me.

Essentially, I use Putty to ssh into my VM. This gives me a re-sizable console. Copy-paste also works better now between Windows and the shell. Since I choose the NAT option for my VM, this approach is less straight-forward. I use the directions in [1] to get access to the VMware network configuration editor. I then forward guest port 22 to a host port (say 8122), and then ssh to it (localhost:8122) from Putty running on my Windows host.

[1] http://alexduan.com/2012/10/15/vmware-player-5-0-network-editor/

Answer (score 0):

I see grub_gfxmode=800x600, have you tried other settings there ?

You might be able to work around this with uvesafb:
http://cosmicb.no/2013/12/25/ubuntu-13-10-console-resolution/